# Failed to parse time string zulu time

Tags: php, php-carbon

when trying to parse a date-time (Zulu) with Carbon, I get the following error:

```
$t = '2021-06-01T21:29:55.155257426Z';
$r = Carbon::parse($t)->setTimezone('UTC');
dd($r);
Could not parse '2021-06-01T21:29:55.155257426Z': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021-06-01T21:29:55.155257426Z) at position 0 (2): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

However, if I remove the last 3 digits, everything works fine, e.g.:

```
$t = '2021-06-01T21:29:55.155257Z';
$r = Carbon::parse($t)->toDateTimeString('microsecond');
dd($r);
"2021-06-01 21:29:55.155257"
```

I'm not sure what to do to parse the microseconds when I have 9 digits (.155257426Z). Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 9 digits isn't microseconds. Carbon's already accepting your timestamp with microseconds, it's rejecting _nano_ seconds. That doesn't fix your problem, but does let you search for the right terms while doing further (re)searching.

Comment: (that said, PHP itself doesn't support nanotime, only microtime, so Carbon _probably_ also doesn't, under the hood?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's DateTime, which underpins Carbon, can only handle fractional seconds up to six digits.

The following will trim it down to six at most:

```php
function trim_nanoseconds($t) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\.(\d+)(.*)$/',
        function($a){
            return sprintf('.%s%s', substr($a[1], 0, 6), $a[2]);
        },
        $t
    );
}
$t = '2021-06-01T21:29:55.123456789Z';

var_dump(fix_nanoseconds($t));
```

Output:

```
string(27) "2021-06-01T21:29:55.123456Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$t = '2021-06-01T21:29:55.155257426Z';
$date = Carbon::parse(preg_replace('/(\d\.\d{6})\d+/', '$1', $t));
```